# How to change already zoomed location in mapview to the current device location

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, mkmapview

I am loading a mapview into a viewcontroller's view. When I load the mapview, it zooms directly to the location of the contact. I have button in the toolbar of my viewcontroller. When I click on this button the mapview should zoom from the already zoomed location to the current location of my iphone. This feature is similar to the one in iphone map app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//did update user location


  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)currentMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

        if(shouldChangeSpan) {
           MKCoordinateSpan span;
           span.latitudeDelta = 0.40;
           span.longitudeDelta = 0.45;
           MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, span);
            [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
            shouldChangeSpan = NO;
        }
    }
```

shouldChangeSpan in an bool declared in h. and set to no in view did load, and set to yes in your button action method.

Comment: I have done the latter part of your answer. Where I am getting wrong is loading the mapview. Is it possible to call map's setregion method twice to the same instance of the mapview. I am getting an exception. Cant figure out the reason.